# Using ASP.NET Identity via WCF services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-identity

I'm working with a legacy asp.net web application that runs on two servers;

- frontend server, IIS web server, accessible from the web
- backend server, can't be accessed from the outside, running IIS and a database.

They communicate using old fashioned asmx-web services.

ASP.Net membership is used for user management and the database is on the backend server. The asmx web services for membership looks pretty much like the example found at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13032/Custom-MembershipProvider-and-RoleProvider-Impleme

My question; Can I do something like this with the ASP.NET Identity (2.0)? Which interfaces will I need to implement? Are there any examples?

I guess I will use WCF instad of asmx :)

Ivar

Comment: I think the solution might be http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Comment: please check [Authentication and Authorization with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 for WCF Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/802435/Authentication-and-Authorization-with-ASP-NET-Iden)